# Rc crawler - make it faster/longer range?

Tags: remote-control

Apologies as I am on a phone at work - but obsessed so here we go hah.

I bought a rocksta crawler, from hobby king. Cool for what it is. But it's deathly slow. Like 25cm/second. Its a great crawler but is there any way to make t faster?

https://hobbyking.com/en_us/basher-rocksta-1-24-4ws-mini-rock-crawler-rtr.html

I'm assuming it's either the motor, gearing, or battery maybe that would need to be upgraded. Or all three. I would really like to see if it's possible to make this faster. It doesn't need to be massively fast. But I'm interested to see what options there are.

Also, if I wanted to extend the range on the transmitter - after some quick phone googling it seems I need to upgrade antenna and a transistor to increase power to antenna / rx?

I'm fairly new to hobby rc / electronics and any advice is appreciated.

Links or even direct advice or anything I can research or to look into specifically later this evening.

Thanks

Comment: There's no one answer. If you simply increase the gearing, it'll run faster on a polished floor and bog down and stall on hostile territory like carpet ... and so on.

Comment: This site is not a discussion site, you need to keep topics limited to electronics. We don't give opinions either as questions and answers here should be specific. See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask and  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic Thanks

Comment: I'm not asking how to use that rc car. I'm asking how can I increase transmitter range. I linked the product so somebody with knowledge can look at specific transmitter and receiver models to better answer my question - with specifics regarding which to solder, which transistor to upgrade, etc. which part is an opinion? I didn't ask if they liked the above product or didn't. I need to increase range on an electronic component that will involve soldering. The other part was asking how can I increase speed - upgrading motor is electronics related. And not an opinion.

Comment: This entire section is for electronics design? Hard to believe everyone on here has a question for a circuit board design and that's it? Please explain why there is an RC tag already established - and what topics would be considered a proper fit for this section? I figured this was considered electronics. Must be something else. I'll post in the arts n crafts and coloring books section lol. Might be a closer fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that simple.  Just like a real car, you can't just change one thing and make it faster and still have everything else work as intended.  You don't know what the various design tradeoffs and limits were.

You can try experimenting with different parameters if you want to see what happens, are trying to learn, and are OK if it ends up damaged as a result.  If you're just want it to "go faster", then the answer is "It can't. You bought the wrong model.".